# JQuery toggle inside callback with ajax takes effect in the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, callback

I have a `<select>` with addresses and a `<button>` that when pressed will fire this `on('click')` event in jQuery. Inside I want to `toggle()` an image and then hide it after the ajax is completed e.g. loader. However, the changes that `toggle()` should perform do not take effect until all of the functionality in the click callback function have been completed.

```
$('#add_existing_address').on('click', function() {
    log($('#loading-image').toggle({queue:false, duration: 10, complete: function() {log('yes');}}));
    sleep(3000);
    var value = $('#EXISING_ADDRESS').val();
    if (value != '') {
        addAddressToOrder(6, value);
        $('#EXISING_ADDRESS').val('');
    }
    //log($('#loading-image').toggle());
    document.getElementById('loading-image').style.display = 'none';
    log(document.getElementById('loading-image').style.display);
});
```

I have made sure that I've setup the `{queue:false}` and duration is 10 milliseconds. The `sleep()` function is a custom one that will slow for 3 seconds so I can see the changes in the page. I have also tried the plain JS to change the display of the image, but it also takes effect after the ajax is completed.

The weird thing is that the first `toggle()` occurrence will return right away and the `log()` will display the result in the console, but the changes will be performed after the last line on the `on()` callback. So far I have not found out why this happens like that.

Basically the output of the function will be:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is basically a single-threaded language in browsers. That means, there is only on single point of execution at any given time.

For animations, that means, that setTimeout() or setInterval() have to be used to execute the animation in reocurring animation frames. That is what jQuery will do for the toggle function. The parameter queue only determines if different animations can be run in parallel (well factually, all animation frames of different animations will run consecutively), or if they are run one after the other.

To explain what happens in your code: First, the toggle method is call, which starts an animation. It sets up some method to do the actual animation in subsequently (asynchronously) called animation frames, and then returns immediatly.
Next, your sleep comes (obviously some kind of loop), which stalls the current execution thread until the period is over. As js is single-threaded, no other execution can take part within this time, so no animation, nothing. After the sleep, the function is executed till the end, executing the style change. Only *after* this has taken part, the single javascript thread is again available for other computations, namely the first created animation frames.

Comment: I understand this, but even when I do the old school way of changing the visibility it does not happen. I have tried out. `document.getElementById('loading-image').style.display = '';` Still the result  is in the end of the `on('click')` Same outcome happens when I move the line in a separate `on('click')`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your explanation. I'm also not 100% sure what you want to achieve, as there is not really a question in your original post. I build a small jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/McNetic/uw1mt8fk/1/. Clicking on Button 1 is roughly what you did in your question. I suspect Button 2 implements what you want to achieve. If I'm mistaken, please explain what you want to do exactly.